# Screen reader and HTML document focus

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm new to this whole ARIA and accessibility aspect of HTML. I have an app where most of the things work properly with screen readers. However, when I click away from any control, i.e. focus on the document, NVDA always reads "*page title* document". I've been trying to stop it from doing that for a while but unsuccessfully.

The best thing I came up with is to add `tabindex=0` to my topmost `DIV` so that it would receive focus on click instead of document, but even then NVDA reads the word "section" when it gets focused. Is there a way to suppress this?

I also tried removing title and adding it back in in a short timeout and then reader says just the word "document" which is fine, but depending on JS activity timeout sometimes flickers empty title as it is executed not that consistently. And requestAnimationFrame is too short, reader doesn't have time to pick the empty title and reads it anyway.

Comment: Add Your Trying Code

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to suppress this? And for which user group? Sighted NVDA users. Why would screen reader users want their settings or default behaviour to be overridden by an application developer??

Comment: As Christophe said, you probably don't want to change the standard behavior for NVDA (and JAWS) users.  However, I'm trying to understand what you're hearing.  For example, on this stackoverflow page, I can tab around and hear the labels on the links.  I then clicked on the text of your question but I did **not** hear "page title document".  Do you hear it?  If not, then it only happens in your app?

Comment: @slugolicious to me NVDA does say it, it say "javascript Screen reader and HTML document focus document" when I click from being say in Search Q&A input field into the text of my question.

Comment: I agree that it is helpful that it reads to a user that focus is no longer on something it was but instead on the document itself, but it reads the entire page title every time. This is not helpful since the tab focus has not changed.

Comment: @pokrishka Are you visually impaired (VI)? If not, then you may not have the qualifications to say that the page title is not helpful. If you are VI and you find that the page title is truly not helpful, then you might have an argument for it, albeit that's only one data point. You'd have to interview other AT users. If you're not VI, I'd suggest turning off your monitor for the day and only use a screen reader, then decide if that page title is helpful or not. It comes in very handy when you step away from your computer then come back later and have to orient yourself.

Answer (score 3):

When you click on the document body, it will become focused and the previously focused control will blur. Screen reader will reflect this change by reading the accessible name of the newly focused widget, namely the document title. This is perfectly normal and entirely expected behavior, there is no need to change that.

You need to keep in mind that your expectations as a sighted developer are entirely not the same as any user, much less visually impaired user. What seems natural and expected to you will be highly confusing to a blind person.

Try being in their place for a while. Put a sleep mask over your eyes and try using your app relying only on keyboard and screen reader. I do that often, and it's a very enlightening experience.

Comment: +1. As a blind person I agree with this. If you're not focused on anything, I'd expect it to go to the top focusable level, i.e the document itself. At least that's what I'm understanding from this question. I could be misinterpreting the question.

Comment: And if you need more info or to validate (from a regulatory perspective), read [WCAG 2.0, guideline 2.4.2 Page Titled: Web pages have titles that describe topic or purpose. (Level A)](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-title.html)